# Flutter: Can I take out widgets?

Tags: flutter, render

It's hard to explain what I want. So I will try to explain with an example:

Now I have a `Card()` And I have a `ListView()` and `Card`' s height is 100

Now I want to move the `ListView` off the `Card`

Image example:

[image]

note: I can have other widgets in `Card`. for example:

```
Card(
  child : Column(
     [
         Text('abc'),
         PopUpListView(),
     ])
)
```

I'm sorry about my bad English :(

Comment: What do you mean by "move the ListView off the Card".Do you want to drag the listview to new widget or just remove the listview from card and re-render it on other widget?

Comment: I mean just want to build listview above card. @KapilSahu

Comment: If I got correctly what you mean, you can use Overlay widget: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Overlay-class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Stack() widget. Try this snippet.

```
Stack( children: [ Card(), ListView(), ], )
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get what do you mean but If you want to place a listview in a card height 100 you can use following code snippet;

```
Container(
        height: 100,
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Card(


          child: ListView(
            children: [
              Text(widget.title),
              Text(widget.title),
              Text(widget.title),

            ],

          ),
        ),
      )
```